# SQL Update Multiple Rows with Multiple Values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-update

I have a list of items that I need to update based on their unique ID in a SQL Server 2005 environment.  I was wondering what the best way of writing a script to update these items.

I know I can simply update a column by writing multiple queries such as:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET HelpLink = 'newLink'
WHERE ID = 5

UPDATE myTable
SET HelpLink = 'newLink2'
WHERE ID = 6
```

Is there any other way of doing this without having to repeat the above update about 20 times?  Repeating the above tends to make a pretty ugly update script.

NOTE: I have a bulk set of items that I will be updating by their unique ID, these items are not coming from a database table.

Comment: Create a table of your updates and then `JOIN` it inside your `UPDATE`.

Comment: Is just making a table, doing 20 inserts then updating my table even better than just writing 20 update statements?  Doesn't seem like much of an improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that you can use case statements which seems to simplify things quite a bit.  This allows me to add multiple items into a single query.

```
UPDATE [MyTable]
SET HelpLink = CASE ID
        WHEN 2 THEN 'MKSDefectsChart.png'
        WHEN 6 THEN 'EPMRisks.png'
        WHEN 7 THEN 'DCTSHardwareChanges.png'
        ELSE NULL
    END
WHERE ID IN (2, 6, 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always update from another table like

```
update myTable
set HelpLink = myOtherTable.HelpLink
from myOtherTable
where myTable.[ID] = myOtherTable.[ID]
```

You'll have to create that other table though